# How to retrieve the data from Eloquent or raw Query in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to retrieve data from DB Week of the month and dates 
am able to get data from MYSQL Query

```
SELECT cnt, `creationdate`, week, weekname, 
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as 'Week Start',
 IF(DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom,
 eom, DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as 'Week End' 
FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(`firstname`) AS 'cnt', `creationdate`, 
FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7 +1) AS week, 
CONCAT('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7) +1) AS weekname, DATE_ADD(`creationdate`,interval -DAY(`creationdate`)+1 DAY) AS firstOfMonth, 
LAST_DAY(`creationdate`) as 'eom' 
FROM `UserDetails` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`creationdate`,'%m/%Y')='06/2017' GROUP BY week ) a
```

Am converting to laravel Raw Query was

```
$monthOfWeaks = DB::table("UserDetails")
            ->select(DB::raw('cnt, creationdate, week, weekname,
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as WeekStart,
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom, eom, DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as WeekEnd'))
->select(DB::raw('COUNT(`firstname`) as cnt, creationdate,
 FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(creationdate) - 1) / 7 +1) as week,
 CONCAT(Week,FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(creationdate) - 1) / 7) +1) as weekname,
 DATE_ADD(creationdate,interval -DAY(creationdate)+1 DAY) as firstOfMonth,
 LAST_DAY(creationdate) as eom'))
            ->whereRaw("DATE_FORMAT(creationdate,'%m/%Y')='06/2017')")
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("WEEK(creationdate)"))
            ->get();
```

It seems like some error but I could not fix in laravel
please give some input to get solve my issues?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```php
DB::select("
SELECT cnt, `creationdate`, week, weekname, 
DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as 'Week Start',
 IF(DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom,
 eom, DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as 'Week End' 
FROM (
 SELECT COUNT(`firstname`) AS 'cnt', `creationdate`, 
FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7 +1) AS week, 
CONCAT('Week ',FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7) +1) AS weekname, DATE_ADD(`creationdate`,interval -DAY(`creationdate`)+1 DAY) AS firstOfMonth, 
LAST_DAY(`creationdate`) as 'eom' 
FROM `UserDetails` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`creationdate`,'%m/%Y')='06/2017' GROUP BY week ) a
");
```

if you don't have any parameter to add to the query that comes from the request/other third party (and so there is no SQL injection risk)

Comment: $sql = 'SELECT cnt, `creationdate`, week, weekname, DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL (week-1) WEEK) as WeekStart, IF(DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY) > eom, eom, DATE_ADD(firstOfMonth,INTERVAL ((week-1)*7+6) DAY)) as 'Week End' FROM ( SELECT COUNT(`firstname`) AS cnt, `creationdate`, FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7 +1) AS week, CONCAT(Week,FLOOR((DAYOFMONTH(`creationdate`) - 1) / 7) +1) AS weekname,........');

$results = DB::select($sql);

showing more errors

Comment: syntax error, unexpected 'Week' (T_STRING)
 i could not fix that issues

Comment: if you run the query manually on your database, it works fine?

Comment: try copy pasting this code and if there are errors, post the entire error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203027/discussion-between-manikandan-s-and-albertosinigaglia).